# How can I get the nested elements of JSON array from fetch API?

Tags: react-native, redux, es6-promise, fetch-api, reducers

I am trying to get some data from server using fetch api in React Native. How can I get it in the JSON format with all fields showing including the nested ones?

I have already tried converting into JSON after getting data from the promise. However, the data is not properly formatted. Fetching the same data using postman gives me all the data and fields populated.

My fetch api looks like this:

```
fetch("https://someurl.com/apps/api/", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      api_key: "somekey",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    params: JSON.stringify({
      device_latitude: deviceLat,
      device_longitude: deviceLong
    })
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(restData => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_REST,
        payload: restData
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

This is my response data from fetch api when I am doing a console log on restData in my reducer:

```
[  
   Object {  
      "restID":1,
      "name":"Rest1",
      "restLocation": null
   },
  Object {  
      "restID":2,
      "name":"Rest2",
      "restLocation": null
   }
]
```

Below is the result when I am calling the endpoint using Postman.

Note: the restLocation field below has more data which is not present when using the fetch api as above:

```
[  
   {  
      "restID":1,
      "name":"Rest1",
      "restLocation":{  
         "id":2,
         "distance":2
      }
   },
   {  
      "restID":2,
      "name":"Rest2",
      "restLocation":{  
         "id":3,
         "distance":1
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: I don't see any `params` option listed in [the parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters). Is that possibly supposed to be a `POST` with a `body`?

Comment: It is in the fetch call 
params: JSON.stringify({
      device_latitude: deviceLat,
      device_longitude: deviceLong
 })
And it is supposed to be a get request only.

Comment: I understand that you have put `params` in the options but the `fetch` API doesn't say that `params` is a valid option which means it is ignored.

Comment: Would you know how to make it into a valid option?

Comment: what is the url you are using with Postman?

Comment: This is the format I am using to call in Postman
https://someurl.com/apps/api?device_latitude=-18.139844&device_longitude=178.426546

I am setting the key values in Params
There is no body.
But have two Headers 
(apikey = "somekey" and Content-type "application/json")

Comment: I think to fully debug I'd want to see your reducers where you are receiving the action you dispatch...Would also be helpful to put the console.log in the exact position you're logging in the above snippet to reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET` parameters should be url encoded and put into the `fetch` url.

For example `GET /test` with postman `PARAMS` `foo1=bar1` and `foo2=bar2` should send a `GET` request to `/test?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2`.

We can encode your params `{device_latitude: deviceLat, device_longitude: deviceLong}` as follows:

```
const url = `https://someurl.com/apps/api/?device_latitude=${deviceLat}&device_longitude=${deviceLong}`;
const fetchableUrl = encodeURI(url);
```

Then `fetch` it in the same way but drop the `params` because they belong in the url:

```
fetch(fetchableUrl, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      api_key: "somekey",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(restData => {
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_REST,
        payload: restData
    });
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thank you!